# Get selected value of dropdown in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropdown

I have a question. I'm beginner in web development.

So basically, I want to get the selected value for the dynamic dropdown in order to edit the form. I'm using the dselect https://github.com/jarstone/dselect/ js file for the dynamic dropdown.

I've tried using this `$('#stock_category').val(data.stock_category);` in order to get the selected value for the dropdown. But still didn't manage to get the selected value.

[image: Datatable]

[image: The modal]

/////////////////////

[image: Inspect dropdown]

When I did inspect the dropdown, it doesnt catch the selected value

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit_button', function() {

  var stock_id = $(this).data('id');

  $('#stock_out_form').parsley().reset();

  $.ajax({

    url: "stock_out_exec.php",

    method: "POST",

    data: {
      stock_id: stock_id,
      action: 'fetch_single'
    },

    dataType: 'JSON',

    success: function(data) {

      $('#stock_category').val(data.stock_category);

      $('#stock_item').val(data.stock_item);

      $('#modal_title').text('Edit Stock Out');

      $('#action').val('Edit');

      $('#submit_button').val('Edit');

      $('#stockOutModal').modal('show');

      $('#hidden_id').val(stock_id);
    }

  })
});
```

```html
<!-- first dynamic dropdown  -->

<select class="form-select" name="stock_category" id="stock_category" onchange="getId(this.value)" required="" style="display: none;">
  <option value="0">Select Category</option>
  <option value="1">PRODUCTS - MARKETING - LOGISTIC</option>
  <option value="2">FREEGIFT</option>
</select>

<div class="dropdown dselect-wrapper ">
  <button class="form-select " data-dselect-text="Select Category" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Category
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <input onkeydown="return event.key !== 'Enter'" onkeyup="dselectSearch(event, this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select', false)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autofocus="">

      <div class="dselect-items" style="max-height:360px;overflow:auto">
        <button class="dropdown-item active" data-dselect-value="0" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Select Category</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">PRODUCTS - MARKETING - LOGISTIC</button>
      </div>

      <div class="dselect-no-results d-none">No results found</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- selected value should be right here  -->
<button class="form-select " data-dselect-text="Select Category" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  Select Category
</button>

<p></p>

<!-- second dynamic dropdown  -->

<select class="form-select" name="stock_item" id="stock_item" data-dselect-search="true" required="" style="display: none;">
  <option value="0">Select Item</option>
</select>


<div class="dropdown dselect-wrapper ">
  <button class="form-select " data-dselect-text="Select Item" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Item
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <input onkeydown="return event.key !== 'Enter'" onkeyup="dselectSearch(event, this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select', false)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autofocus="">
      <div class="dselect-items" style="max-height:360px;overflow:auto">
        <button class="dropdown-item active" data-dselect-value="0" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Select Item</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dselect-no-results d-none">No results found</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button class="form-select " data-dselect-text="Select Item" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  Select Item
</button>
```

Comment: `$('#stock_category').val(data.stock_category);` normally sets the value and doesn't get it. To get the value, you would normally use `$('#stock_category').val();`.

Comment: I've already tried this but still didn't manage to get the selected value for the dynamic dropdown.

Comment: What did you get, when you did `console.log($('#stock_category').val())`?

Comment: It is 0  value when i tried that

Comment: @NisaRezuan look at the HTML to see if the values of your options are correct

Comment: Have you selected something else than `Select Category` option at that time? If not, then it works correctly, since the `Select Category` option has a value of 0.

Comment: The dropdown was on the default value which is Select Category, the thing is when I click the edit button. The dynamic dropdown doesnt on the selected value. Instead it's on the default value.

Comment: I think it's because of I'm using additional dropdown https://github.com/jarstone/dselect/ js file.

Comment: Your code, as provided and with server-side code extrapolated, works fine with `$('#stock_category').val();`.  See this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/srex1p6c/  open browser console, run fiddle, select "cat 2", click "click me" - shows "2".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a **working snippet** that **demonstrates the issue**.  Only include enough code to demonstrate the issue.  For example `$(document).on('click', '.edit_button',` doesn't seem to be relevant as there's no edit_button in your HTML.  Equally, don't include any server-side code - as this is a js question, only include the *rendered* HTML.  Include when/where you are checking the value (as your current code doesn't include this).

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing the option element with: `$('#stock_category').find("option:selected")`

Then try: `$('#stock_category').find("option:selected").val()`

and if that doesn't work, just grab the text with: `$('#stock_category').find("option:selected").text()`

- and if there's extra whitespace, just strip it: `$('#stock_category').find("option:selected").text().trim()`

---

### Edit 1, Showing copy element in dev console

##### Right link on Element + Inspect

[image: Inspect Element]

##### Find Select in Element's Pane, should already be highlighted blue, and Copy. (when you hover over elements in the pane, the element on the page is highlighted)

[image: Copy Element]

##### When you Copy Element, it will copy the select field + ALL the options it contains. It should look like a complete mess when pasted. You can Chop out some Options and get rid of actual values (if needed) just be careful not to remove the option that is selected

---

### Edit 2

This works: `document.getElementById("stock_category").value`
For some reason I can't access it using JQuery, but I can in Vanilla JS.

Comment: Already tried this, but still not working.

Comment: How annoying. Could you inspect the select element in the console, copy it + the options and then add it in your original question?- that way we can paste it in a local env or codepen and play around with it. You can cut out some options if there's like 150 of them, just make sure you don't delete the selected one!

Comment: Okay. Already added that

Comment: See edit, I've explained how to do it. there will be no `<?php` in the copy- it'll just be raw HTML

Comment: Thank you. Already did. Can you take a look

Comment: Thanks! I messed around with it locally and added what I would do. Very odd Js you're using.. it should be a lot easier but that's the only way I could find

Comment: I played around with it a bit more and corrected my answer. for some reason you can't access the value using JQuery, but you can with normal JavaScript. Odd